# Zend_Form - prefix text using decorator

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-decorators, html

I want to prefix the form title within the form tags, but above the form elements.

```
<form>
 <h3>Login Form</h3>
 <!-- form elements -->
</form>
```

I do not want to use a view script.

I thought of using the Description decorator, but that appears to be only available to the elements.

How do I set an arbitrary description for a form, and position it (either append / prepend) within the form tags? I have a feeling I need to play with the HtmlTag decorator but I've played with it and can't get the right results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical. Ask a question, work out the solution.

```
$form->setDecorators(array(
    array(
        'Description',
        array(
            'tag' => 'div',
            'class' =>'title'
        )
    ),
    'FormElements',
    'Form'
))
->setDescription('Enter Login Credentials:');
```

Depending where you place the description decorator will determine where in the form tags it displays, i.e. place above 'FormElements' to display above the elements; place below 'FormElements' to display the description below the elements; place below the 'Form' decorator to display after the form tags.